# ng-show nested in ng-repeat won't update

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-show

I've looked all over SO and Google and seen a whole bunch of reasons why ng-show wouldn't work inside of ng-repeat (scope issues, binding issues, etc.) but I can't quite pin down why mine isn't working. I was hoping that an extra pair of eyes could help me out. I'm very new to Angular, so hopefully my code makes **some** sense.

**The goal**: when `$scope.current_set` changes, the visible `lmf-optionset` changes. Currently, only the first optionset loads via `Decision_Tree:loaded`, and then when I try to load the next one via `clickbox:clicked`, `$scope.current_set` changes, but the view won't update.

JS

```
angular.module('lmf.option_set', [])
  .controller('OptionsetCtrl', ['$scope', 'Optionsets', 'Decision_Tree',
    function($scope, Optionsets, Decision_Tree) {
      $scope.Optionsets = Optionsets;
      $scope.current_set = {
        name: null
      };

      $scope.$on('clickbox:clicked', function() {
        $scope.current_set = Decision_Tree.get_next_optionset();
      });

      $scope.$on('Decision_Tree:loaded', function() {
        $scope.current_set = Decision_Tree.get_next_optionset();
      });
    }
  ])
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller='OptionsetCtrl'>
  <div ng-repeat='set in Optionsets.option_sets'>
    <div ng-show="set.name == current_set.name" lmf-optionset="{{set.name}}"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently `lmf-optionset` creates an isolated scope for each entry. These child scopes have link to parent's `current_set`, but they doesn't maintain a two-way binding. So when you are replacing the `current_set` **value** in you event handlers, child scopes are unaware that `current_set` was changed, and they are still referring to the old value.

You can either rewrite your event handlers like this:

```
$scope.current_set.name = Decision_Tree.get_next_optionset().name;
```

Or you can use `controller as` construction like this:

```
<div ng-controller='OptionsetCtrl as vm'>
  <div ng-repeat='set in Optionsets.option_sets'>
    <div ng-show="set.name == vm.current_set.name" lmf-optionset="{{set.name}}"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```